# Anchor in link not working on mobile devices in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mobile, anchor-scroll

"Prices" anchor link seems to be working in Safari and Firefox, just not in Chrome.

Live page in question: https://www.effortlessmobileauto.com/servicesPhoenix/servicesPhoenix.html#contact

Page needs to automatically scroll to #contact div upon clicking the links for "Services" and "Prices" on mobile devices. Anchor should take you to where the contact information begins. You'll notice this works perfectly for the "Services" page, but no matter what I anchor to on the "Prices" page, the page always loads partially through the main nav rather than at #contact.

Does anyone know what is going on here? I have scoured the code for both pages and cannot find what is causing this to happen. Please let me know if you have questions or need additional info.

Comment: Maybe because your contact div is already on top so that's why no need for scroll

Comment: Please include any relevant code directly in the code. See how to make a [mcve].

Comment: Updated the post to include that the issue is only prevalent in Chrome. Anchors work in Firefox and Safari.

Comment: Also, @GauravBhardwaj the contact div is not at the top, there is an entire nav before it. The idea here is to jump right past the nav after navigating to this page.